# Encryption using SHA1

Tags: encryption, sha1, hmacsha1

I am developing a large application and i need encryption when a data is traveling between two machines in different continents. I have never worked on encryption. I want a simple encryption which can be handled in PHP / Ruby / Python without any dependencies.

So i decided to use HMAC SHA1.

```
$pad=hash_hmac("sha1","The quick brown....","mykey");
```

This is what i found out after some research on the internet.

How hard it is to decrypt it if someone doesn't know the key? Also, any alternatives to this?

UPDATE - thanks for all the responses. Problem solved.

Comment: This is a hash, not a cipher: you can't decrypt it without going through all the possibilities and checking them!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's impossible to decrypt it, even if you know the key.  HMAC SHA1 is a keyed hash algorithm, not encryption.

A hash is a cryptographic one-way function that always generates a value of the same length (I think SHA1 is 128-bits) regardless of the length of the input.  The point of a hash is that, given the output value, it's computationally infeasible to find an input value to produce that output.  A keyed hash is used to prevent rainbow table attacks.  Even if you know the key you can't reverse the hash process.

For encryption you want to look at AES.

Comment: SHA1 is 160 bits long (whatever the input size)

Comment: Thanks poupou.  I knew I should have looked that up.

Answer (score 1):

SHA1 is a one-way-hash function, by definition it is not decryptable by anyone.  The question becomes if you have a plaintext T that hashes to H.  How hard is it to find another T which also hashes to H.

According to Wikipedia, for SHA1, the best known brute force attack would take 2^51 evlautions to find a plain text that matches.

If you need actual encryption where you can reverse the process, you should take a look at AES256.

See: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

For a general discussion on this.

Answer (score 1):

Like Andrew said *SHA1* is an hash algorithm and cannot be used for encryption (since you cannot get back the original value). The *digest* it produce can be used to validate the integrity of the data.

An HMAC is a construct above an hash algorithm that accept a key. However it's not for meant for encryption (again it can't be decrypted) but it allows you to **sign** the data, i.e. with the same key you'll be able to ensure the data was not tampered with during it's transfer.

Foe encryption you should look at using AES or, if applicable to your application, HTTPS (which will deal with more issues than you want to know about ;-)

Answer (score 0):

SHA-1 , MD-5 are all one way Hashing algorithms.
They just generate a lengthy string. Each and every string when subjected to these functions will yield you a lengthy string which cannot be retained back.

They are far from encryptions.

If you are looking for encryption algorithms , go for AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) , DES (Data Encryption Standard) Algorithms.

Answer (score -2):

As I say, this is a hash, so not an encryption/decryption problem. If you want to implement a straightforward encryption algorithm, I would recommend looking into XOR encryption. If the key is long enough (longer than the message) and your key sharing policy is suitably secure, this is a one time pad; otherwise, it can potentially be broken using statistical analysis.

Comment: -1 for suggesting XOR encryption on a general security question (sorry)

Comment: Why? I know it's not exactly the best, but given the OP tried to use a SHA1 hash to encrypt data, I figured that an easy to understand and implement algorithm would be a good place to start learning.

Comment: @owlstead - XOR is fine assuming good, high-quality stream of non-repeating key material. It's basically the way RC4 works. The main problem is getting a stream of key data with high enough entropy to be useful, and being able to use the same material at the other. That said I've given this answer a -1 for suggesting the OP implement his own encryption algorithm. Encryption is notoriously hard to get right, and even with a known algorithm implementation details can lead to weaknesses. You're much better off using an existing, mature library.

Comment: @Xophmeister if this were a "learning" question, then I would have to agree that some kind of XOR encryption could be a good way to start learning. But that was never the question of the OP.

Comment: @AndrewCooper a XOR is fine as the last part of a encryption model where a known good algorithm is creating a key stream. And if Xophmeister would have proposed, say, AES in CTR mode with a well choosen NONCE, I would not have complained. But proposing XOR encryption or a one time pad for a real life encryption problem... Nah.