# Using CryptoPP::HexDecoder( )

Tags: c++, visual-c++, encryption, hex, crypto++

I am playing with Cryptopp for ther first time and I found an example to encode to Hex...All is well.
Now I want to decode std::string produced into original string but all I get is empty string.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "../cryptopp562/sha.h"
#include "../cryptopp562/filters.h"
#include "../cryptopp562/hex.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    CryptoPP::SHA1 sha1;
    std::string source = "Panawara";  
    std::string hash = "";
    std::string original= "" ;

    CryptoPP::StringSource(source, true, new CryptoPP::HashFilter(sha1, new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(hash))));
    std::cout << hash;
    std::cout << "\n";

    CryptoPP::StringSource (hash, new CryptoPP::HexDecoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(original)));  // the result is always empty String
    std::cout << original;
    std::cout << "\n";

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Of course, way to late, but I just want to ask: You are aware, that SHA is only a hash generator, not an symmetric encryption algorithm, like AES? See more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929357/encryption-using-sha1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> CryptoPP::StringSource(source, true,
>     new CryptoPP::HashFilter(sha1,
>         new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(hash))));
> ```

Don't use anonymous declarations. Name your variables. Use this instead:

```
CryptoPP::StringSource ss(source, true,
    new CryptoPP::HashFilter(sha1,
        new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(hash)
    )));
```

Do it for all of them.

Also see [CryptoPP HexDecoder output empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327066/cryptopp-hexdecoder-output-empty).